# invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'uint8_t

Tags: arduino

im having a problem, i just bought an arduino and i was wondering if anyone could help, here is my code. (i am just trying to get two leds to fade in and out).

```
int ledCount = 2;
int ledPins [ ] = {11,12 };
int brightness = 0;
int delayTime = 10;
void setup() {
 pinMode(ledPins, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  while(brightness < 255)
  {
    analogWrite(ledPins, brightness);
    delay(delayTime);
brightness = brightness + 1;
  }
while(brightness > 0)
  {
 analogWrite(ledPins, brightness);
 delay(delayTime);
     brightness = brightness - 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an array to `analogWrite` or `pinMode`, where it is expecting a `uint8_t`.

Arduino pin manipulation functions will only handle a single pin at a time. There are ways around that, by directly manipulating the AVR/ARM GPIO registers, but those can be finicky (not recommended for use unless you ***really need*** speed).

The reason it says `int *` is because under the hood, arrays in C/C++ are represented as pointers.

If you want to `analogWrite` or `pinMode` to both LEDs, you will have to call the function once for each LED. Example:

```
analogWrite(ledPins[0], brightness);
analogWrite(ledPins[1], brightness);
```

Or

```
for(int currentLED = 0;currentLED < ledCount;i++){
    analogWrite(ledPins[currentLED], brightness);
}
```

In the context of your program:

```
int ledCount = 2;
int ledPins [] = {11, 12};

int brightness = 0;
int delayTime = 10;

#define INCREASE 1
#define DECREASE 2
int brightness_change = INCREASE;

void setup(){
    for(int i = 0;i < ledCount;i++){
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop(){
    while(brightness < 255 && brightness_change == INCREASE){
        brightness = brightness + 1;
    }
    while(brightness > 0 && brightness_change == DECREASE){
        brightness = brightness - 1;
    }
    if(brightness == 255){
        brightness_change = DECREASE;
    }
    if(brightness == 0){
        brightness_change = INCREASE;
    }

    for(int current_led = 0;current_led < ledCount;current_led++){
        analogWrite(current_led, brightness;
    }
    delay(delayTime;
}
```

Not tested, but it should work.